# How to read paged rows from an excel or ods file?

Tags: java, excel, odf, ods

We are using java and [ODF Toolkit](http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/) for reading rows from ods and excel files.

The problem is that , even if you want to read only 1 row ,the whole document is loaded and the memory usage for a 50.000 rows of ods file is around 350 MBs .

So im searching for a way to read rows by paging . Any chance

Edit1 : Please dont sugges [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) , works just like ODF Toolkit.

Edit2 : I accepted an answer but it only works with Excel files , and there's no answer for ODS files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach may be to load rows using JDBC.

There are various JDBC Excel drivers around including this:

https://code.google.com/p/sqlsheet/

See also:

[Connecting to excel sheet using jdbc without specifying DSN to Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181119/connecting-to-excel-sheet-using-jdbc-without-specifying-dsn-to-excel-sheet)

Comment: sqlsheet is a good idea. Do you have any solution for ODS files ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if there are any JDBC drivers for ODS. If the spreadsheet can be set up as an ODBC datasource there's the JDBC<>ODBC bridge. Don't know if that would work for you. Anyway, I have never actually done any of this (just knew that it was possible for Excel) so you'd need to investigate further.

Comment: SQLSheet still uses POI underneath

Answer (score 1):

Converting .ods to .xls /.xlsx and using the more established poi api might be helpful.It allows to read specific rows/cells and you can use the same to prevent overshooting your memory limits.

Comment: Are you sure that its not loading the whole document to memory? ODF has all the methods to read cells or rows and stuff, but when you want to get the table , it loads all to memory.

Comment: I'm redirecting you to this on SO  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147585/excel-sheet-poi-validation-out-of-memory-error.Hope it helps give you some idea.The first suggestion there is fairly obvious but the 2nd one is what is important.

Comment: Ive read that question and answers , POI is not working any different than the ODF toolkit.However , theres one suggestion for solution of the paging need , SAX processing. Im not desperate enough to go for it yet.Thanks for the view though :)

Comment: +1 for the use of POI. The Java ODF toolkit is not for the novice (as of early 2020, it appears to have been retired, and no longer active)